# how to add more than one form to a flexible on a html page

Tags: php, html

I have an html structure with 5 container 
1: The header
2: The Right sidebar
3: The Main content area (which will be holding the "flexbox")
4: The Buttons container (where all the Flex box display item buttons are placed
5: The footer

I want to add About 20 forms to the flex box and each of the form will have a it's own button on the buttons container so that I can go to any of the forms by clicking it own button.

So, just help me with a way of linking all of my forms to it's own button

this is a bit of the code

```
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1">flex item1</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">flex item2</div>
<div class="flex-item item3">flex item 3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need a way of assigning a button to each of the items

Comment: Don't describe your code; show it to us! See [ask].

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) And maybe take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)